# Link Assembling

Tags: windows, lua, hyperlink, execute

So I tried to make a script where a specific program opens the link but it only opens a part of it, can someone please help?

```lua
elseif result == "GOTO_ULTRABOOK_LEVEL" then
local randomLevelDigit = _G.math.random(1, 14)
local lvlURL = "https://ab-in-adventure.appspot.com/embed?levelId=1-" .. randomLevelDigit .. "&levelName=level-" .. randomLevelDigit
local basilisk = "Basilisk-Portable.exe"
--openURL()
_G.os.execute(basilisk, lvlURL)
```

Comment: What does "only opens a part of it" mean?

Comment: `_G.os.execute('""'..basilisk..'" "'..lvlURL..'""')`

Answer (score 2):

`_G.os.execute(basilisk, lvlURL)` won't work. The second argument `lvlURL` is ignored as [os.execute](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.execute) only takes one string argument.

In the manual you'll find `os.execute ([command])`. This tells you that `os.execute` has a single optional parameter. Single because there is nothing else in the parentheses. Optional because it is in square brackets.

So in order to make it work simply provide the complete shell command to `os.execute` as a single string.

As you're already using the string concatenation operator in your snippet you'll know what to do.